# How to reference an external typelib from an interface defined for proxy/stub generation

Tags: com, idl, office-automation, midl, typelib

I have an interface `IFoo` that references the Office typelib `MSO.DLL`. I want the proxy/stub code (`dlldata.c`) to be generated for my interfaces when my IDL is compiled. As I understand it, in order for midl.exe to produce the proxy/stub code, the interface(s) must be declared at the root level of my IDL. However, the `importlib` statements can only be within the `library` block. Consequently, the type I'm trying to reference (`Office._CustomXMLParts`) doesn't exist when `IFoo` is compiled. Is there any way to solve this, other than custom proxy/stub implementation or using `IDispatch` instead of the full referenced type?

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

[
    object,
    uuid(02F84D34-91DB-400B-94C9-71ABCD6F077D),
    version(1.0),
    nonextensible,
    pointer_default(unique),
    oleautomation,
    dual
]
interface IFoo : IDispatch
{
    [id(0x461A47A4)] HRESULT Bar([in] Office._CustomXMLParts* customXmlParts);
};

[
    uuid(CC76135E-FA22-4437-8719-3FFADE38D72B),
    version(1.0)
]
library FooLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
    importlib("mso.dll");

    interface IFoo;
}
```

The error I receive is:

```
error MIDL2025: syntax error : expecting a type specification near "Office"
```

I tried moving the interface definitions below the `library` block, but I get a different error.

```
error MIDL2009: undefined symbol : _CustomXMLParts [ Parameter 'customXmlParts' of Procedure 'Bar'  ]
```

Comment: Ah rats, you misspelled the interface name.  It is `Office::_CustomXMLParts`, XML in capitals.  You must `#import "mso.dll"` in your .cpp files so the compiler knows the definition of the interface, it can't get it from the IDL.

Comment: Casing doesn't really matter in IDL, as all type library and IDispatch operations are supposed to be case-insensitive. Changing the case here has no effect. My results are the exactly same no matter what case I use.

Comment: FWIW: I updated my post with the correct casing. Question stands.

Comment: Rats because I lost half an hour of my life trying to get it to compile.  C++ is most certainly case-sensitive, unlike VB.  And requires `::`, not `.` to match the #import definitions.  I get a clean build for a sample ATL project with a proxy/stub, the #import directive is essential.  Good luck.

Comment: I know you know this stuff well, Hans, but you're a little off your game today. :) C++ is case sensitive. IDL is not. I just ran a test where I use OFFICE._CUSTOMXMLPARTS instead of the "correct" casing. With the interface definitions in the library block, even this totally wrong casing compiles fine in the IDL. The C++ is always produced with the correct casing. The MIDL compiler doesn't care what case you use -- it always produces the correct case for the C++. `HRESULT ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *Bar )( IFoo * This, /* [in] */ /* external definition not present */ _CustomXMLParts *customXmlParts);`

Comment: Ultimately, this is not my question, though. It doesn't matter which type library I use, or which case I use to refer to the type library or the type. The problem is that I can't seem to use IDL to produce proxy/stub code as long as my interface uses an external type, since I can't produce proxy/stub code with the interface definitions in the `library` block, and I can't `importlib` the external type library outside the `library` block.

Comment: Try to focus less on what I might have done wrong or how I did not answer the question, more on getting that Bar declaration to compile.  To match the declaration that was #imported from mso.dll, it requires either `Office::_CustomXMLParts` or you'll have to squirrel a `using namespace Office;` somewhere.  It is still not obvious whether you actually used #import.  Required.

Comment: @HansPassant: Please try to focus on my question. :) I know full well that I need to `#import "mso.dll"` and had already done so before asking this question. I'm not talking about the C++. I'm talking about the IDL. With the interface declarations outside the library block, the IDL does not compile (and therefore does not produce any C++). With the interface declarations inside the library block, the IDL compiles, but it does not produce the C++ for the proxy/stub (dlldata.c). Everything else I fully know how to deal with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128744/discussion-between-michael-gunter-and-hans-passant).

Comment: [`oleview`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0kh9f4c.aspx) can generate IDL from TLB. I haven't tried actually compiling the result though.

Comment: I don't have a TLB because my IDL won't compile when the interface declarations are at the root (as required to produce dlldata.c).

Comment: I meant, generate IDL from mso.dll, then `import` that (just like you do `oaidl.idl`, say).

Comment: I'll try that. I've never used imports other than the standard. I half expect it to try to put the defined interfaces into my type library, but maybe that's not the case. Thanks.